# Активация деструктора класса, созданного через new

Tags: c++

Вызывается ли при удалении класса, созданного через new, с помощью delete, его деструктор?

Comment: А как же иначе? Конечно.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, а то я перепутал с другой фичей. Подскажи, а можно как-то просто закрыть вопрос или только удалить?

Comment: Либо удалить, либо поставить галочку на чьем-то ответе. (Можно самому написать ответ и себе поставить галочку.)

Comment: Кстати, вы могли бы это проверить. Создать класс, деструктор которого печатает что-то в консоль и проверить...

Comment: Да лучше такого уровня вопрос удалить - это самые-самые азы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, если указатель, переданный в `delete` не является нулевым, то будет вызван деструктор (если таковой имеется) для объекта.

> **8.3.5 Delete**
>   6. If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is not a null pointer value, the delete-expression will invoke the destructor (if
>   any) for the object or the elements of the array being deleted. In the
>   case of an array, the elements will be destroyed in order of
>   decreasing address (that is, in reverse order of the completion of
>   their constructor; see 15.6.2).